# Swift Hex to byte (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, hex, crc

I have commands in hex format (for example 0x01, 0x02, etc)

How to enter them in xcode (what type of variables)? And how to convert them into bytes to calculate the checksum (CRC8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your hexa string back to array of UInt8 using this extension :

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var hexa2Bytes: [UInt8] {
        let hexa = Array(self)
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 2).compactMap { UInt8(String(hexa[$0..<$0.advanced(by: 2)]), radix: 16) }
    }}
```

Comment: @DmitriyToropkin Good.Mark it as correct answer so others can make use of it.